# Override a class in rails/refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I'm using refinery cms and want to override (add a method) to their page class.  I've tried doing a Page.class_eval in a file in the initializers directory but it only seems to work on the first page load.  after that the method i added disappears.  any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I looked at that page but couldn't apply it to what I want to do; but it sounds as though I want to do the same as you

Comment: I did but I'd go with what @parndt suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this would help you?

[Augmenting a model from an external gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018701/augmenting-a-model-from-an-external-gem/4019091#4019091)

parndt